# How to stubb a private method call of my tested class

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, mockito

I am actually trying to Test a method, that needs a DB Connection (i cant make it at this moment), so i want to test the method ignoring the DB Connection.

```
@Test
public void Test(){
         ExampleClass ex = new ExampleClass();

         ex.methodA();
}
```

My method is calling an inner class, and that class is calling the private method that broke my test. I cant actually call the private method of the Tested class, because is not visible.

```
public class ExampleClass{

      public methodA(){
                    .......
                    return new innerClass();
      }

         private class innerClas{
            public methodB(){
                             ..........
                              ..........
                              Object a = send(....); //This is my DB Connections that crashes.
            }

            private send(....){
                       .......... 
                         .........
            }
         }
}
```

I need to ignore the Send method of the Tested class, because there is the DB Connection. If i can stub that send, of ignore it will be enough.

Comment: Object a  is created at methodB.

Comment: You can't use partial mocking/spies with *private* method with real Mockito, you need PowerMockito to do that. But be careful about that, that isn't a dependency you want buy in lightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create object of `innerClass` in `ExampleClass#methodA()`. Instead, inject this object into `ExampleClass` through constructor or method.

Now, from the test class mock `innerClass` using Mockito or equivalent and return your mocked result from the target method that you want to avoid calling the real stuff.

By the way for private method mocking use PoweMock, add the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleClass.class)
public class MyTest{
}
```

Comment: Its legacy code, im actually making the test, i cant change the code :(

Comment: I see. Which method you are trying to test? I see `methodB()` call` send()` but, the test calls `methodA()` only. I am assuming both `methodB()` and `send()` belong to `innerClass`, is that correct? Unless you can't use a mock instance of `innerClass`, you can't prevent database call from `send()`. By the way instead of calling `methodA()` to get `innerClass` object why don't you directly create `mock` instance of `innerClass`? Please make the syntaxes of your example correct.

Comment: Sory for the bad syntax. Yes, you were right with your assuming.
And how should i mock that private innedClass?

Comment: I assume you are trying to innerClass#methodB() and mock innerClass#send(). To mock private method innerClass#send() use PowerMock as mentioned in the answer. I'll update the answer with your example.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing - how do you call methodB() from your test (even without mocking) since you declared innerClass as private? You can't even refer InnerClass from outside. Then how do you call mnethodB() from outside the ExampleClass?

Comment: Im calling the methodA, that returns a new inner class, who instantly calls methodB when its instanced. (I didnt try the powermock you said, im arriving to my pc in some hours and i will try)

Comment: Sorry for the late. I solved it with PowerMock, thanks!